# Inserting a blank into the second row in a specific column, python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

Looking to add a blank into a specific column, in this case column 1 row 2.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i97we.png)

The above image shows 2 columns, in the second column I need to insert a blank cell, i.e. push the three rows (with text) in column 1 down.

What Im trying to do is the below:

There are images in the url Im scraping, all except one image has a figure caption (the first).

The 'figure.article__main-hero article__main-hero-image' is the figure that does not have a figure caption. My thinking was to scrape this and return a blank, which is does. Question is how do I insert that blank into the 2nd row column 1? At the moment, the cap_meta list is inserted in column 1 starting from the second row, need to start from the third. When this happens, the incorrect caption is associated with the image. Another way of putting this is, if there is no figure caption associated with a figure, insert a blank, if there is, insert the figure caption.

I am using pandas here but does not have to be.

```
url = 'https://www.homestolove.com.au/resort-style-home-three-birds renovations-22500'
driver.get(url)

url_content = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')
matches_img_url = re.findall(r'img .*?srcset="(.*?)"', url_content)

main_image = []
cap_meta = []
credit = []

for j in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('figure.article__main- hero article__main-hero-image'):
    main_image.append(j.text)

for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//figcaption[@class = "content-body__inline-image-caption"]'):
    cap_meta.append(i.text)

for k in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "content body__inline-image-credit"]'):
    credit.append(k.text)

#rows = zip(matches_img_url, main_image, cap_meta)

matches_img_df = pd.DataFrame(matches_img_url)
metadata_df = pd.DataFrame(cap_meta)
credit_df = pd.DataFrame(credit)
main_image_df = pd.DataFrame(main_image)

scrapped_urls = pd.concat([matches_img_df, main_image_df, metadata_df, credit_df], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
scrapped_urls.to_csv('scrapped_urls_test2.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

****************EDIT *******************

```
url = 'https://www.homestolove.com.au/resort-style-home-three-birds 
renovations-22500'
driver.get(url)

url_content = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')
matches_img_url = re.findall(r'img .*?srcset="(.*?)"', url_content)

data = [{"url": url} for url in matches_img_url]

caption_xpath = './/figcaption[@class="content-body__inline-image- caption"]'
for idx, caption in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(caption_xpath)):
    data[idx]["caption"] = caption.text or ""

credit_xpath = './/span[@class = "context body__inline-image-credit"]'
for idx, credit in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(credit_xpath)):
    data[idx]["credit"] = credit.text or ""

image_css = "div.article__hero-container"
for idx, hero_image in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(image_css)):
    data[idx]["caption"] = hero_image.text

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('scrapped_urls_test2.csv', mode='a', index=False)code here
```

Comment: From what I've understood, you essentially want a `""` to show up anywhere you don't have a caption. If that's correct, then you could likely do something like... `i.text or ""` and that should have you covered, I think?

Comment: That is correct. Where would I implement ""? I did use a bool to say if  .//figcaption[@class = "content-body__inline-image-caption"] does not exist then do.... but I realised it always  exists. I need to tie it to a specific image, where caption does not exists. I thinking I need to find away ..... if the <figure element does not have element <figcaption then do something. How to write this?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code? Once that's complete, I can safely make the necessary edits to show you where to add that. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Python's ducktyping to accomplish this.

```py
url = 'https://www.homestolove.com.au/resort-style-home-three-birds renovations-22500'

url_content = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')
matches_img_url = re.findall(r'img .*?srcset="(.*?)"', url_content)

data = [{"url": url} for url in matches_img_url]

image_css = "figure.article__main-hero article__main-hero-image"
for idx, image in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(image_css)):
    data[idx]["image"] =  image.text

caption_xpath = './/figcaption[@class="content-body__inline-image-caption"]'
for idx, caption in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(caption_xpath)):
    data[idx]["caption"] = caption.text or ""

credit_xpath = './/span[@class = "context body__inline-image-credit"]'
for idx, credit in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(credit_xpath):
    data[idx]["credit"] = credit.text or ""

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('scrapped_urls_test2.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

A key caveat to this solution is that `item.text` **must** be defined as a property. If it's undefined, then this will fail. (There's another way to achieve this if that's an edge-case to account for.)

This solution relies on the fact that many empty datatypes will evaluate to an equivalent of `None` or `False` in Python, which can be thought of as "lower priority" to `""`, so Python will set the corresponding variable to `""`, as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, although did not work for me but gave me the ground work. I change the for loop order and changed to the div class as I noticed figure. was not enumerating. image_css = "div.article__hero-container" for idx, hero_image in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(image_css)): data[idx]["caption"] = hero_image.text